# terminal stopped working and became blank

Tags: command-line

i did the "sudo apt-get upgrade sudo apt-get install synpatic"
and while it was upgrading, first the ununtu software center which was opened, got closed due to an error and then terminal became blank and stopped working, i also had google chrome and VLC player opened at that time, what happened? did i lose anything? or i can just do the "sudo apt-get upgrade sudo apt-get install synpatic" again and no problem?

PS: i had skype installed on my ubuntu already but in upgrade it was downloading skype-bin, why was that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both apt-get, software center, automatic updates (and synaptic) use a lock file to try to make sure that two updates or installations are not occurring at the same time.  Usually, conflicts are handled as they are supposed to be but it's not a good idea to run multiple install/upgrade programs at the same time.

Restart the computer and do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and see if it works.  If it does then you do

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

If you have any further problems, have a look at [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure).